# Visual Studio Online website gets deployed to Azure in debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, web.config-transform

I created an ASP.NET MVC web application project which I commit to Visual Studio Online (Git repo) and is linked to a Windows Azure website for automatic deployment (if all unit tests succeed). My project contains the default Web.Release.config transformation that should remove the Web.config attribute `/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug` which should (amongst others) enable script bundling.

It appears the web.config transformation is not executed during deployment, so I guess it doesn't use the Release configuration during build/deployment.

I also don't find a way to alter the default build definition in Visual Studio Online.

How can I get Visual Studio Online/Azure to deploy my project using Release build configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your Build Definition to specify you want the build to be a release build.  To do this, in Team Explorer,  go to the **Builds** section.  Right-click on your build definition and select **Edit Build Definition**.  In the Build Definition settings, click on the **Process** node.  Under **2.Build**, set your **Configurations** to **Any CPU|Release**.

Here's a screen capture for reference.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: I have this set and it still won't transform the web.config file for me. (Large problems because all of the documentation online is contradictory since they've changed everything lately.)