# Use different databases in test and production

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio online, visual studio 2013, and Microsoft Azure. My development environment is in VS2013, I commit my project changes to visual studio online, which is configured to deploy my project to Azure. In Azure, I have a SQL database that I can connect to from my website (though I haven't done so yet).

How do I switch between my development environment (where I want to have a separate SQL database deployed locally) to my Azure SQL database?

Comment: I am aware that this is normally done with a config file, and I've done so in Java development many times. This seems different because of the automatic deployment to the Azure website. I'd appreciate any assistance or resources.

Comment: I think you are looking for [.NET Config Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: To add to the suggestion by @jomsk1e [here is an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) (though somewhat old) of setting up transforms for web deployment - may help point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can set a connection string override in Azure Portal. Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work.aspx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219536/visual-studio-online-website-gets-deployed-to-azure-in-debug-mode and setup a build config and web.config transformation to use

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yeah I saw in jomsk1e's link something about Azure having override settings for the web config also. Thank you. I will definitely use that. However I'm still trying to wrap my head around how a "transform" would work for my scenario in the traditional (non-Azure) way. It says the transform gets performed when you deploy: how does it know when you're deploying (e.g. what triggers the transform)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the connection string for the website in the Azure portal.

[image: Website Connection String Settings]

You'll find this under the **Configure** tab.

On startup, Azure will replace the connection string settings in the `web.config` with the values from the portal.

This has the benefits of not needing to store sensitive information in the transform.